# Is there a Delphi 5 component that can handle .png files

Tags: delphi, delphi-5

Is there a  Delphi 5 component that can handle .png files?

Answer (score 1):

You can use TPNGImage. Download from [here](http://www.isheu.com/data_5095_1.aspx)
Also you can check Delphi PNG libraries [here](http://delphi.pjh2.de/articles/graphic/png.php)

Comment: That page says "This is a spin off from the original TPNGImage component from Gustavo Daud." That means **it's not allowed to be distributed.** Daud did not authorize spin-offs of his code, and Embarcadero bought the rights a few years ago. The only way the code can be distributed now is if it's exactly as Daud originally distributed it, according to his own license. That's likely why the SourceForge project that the code came from is now defunct.

Comment: Background information: http://blogs.embarcadero.com/nickhodges/2008/08/13/39100 - The license said: `This component may be distributed freely over the internet only when containing the exact same files from the original packaging.`

Answer (score 0):

TMS and DevExpress both can handle png files.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the GDI+ delphi interface from progdigy can be used with D5.  Its not a simple plug-in to enable PNG support, but on the other hand, it can load a wide variety of file types.  So its another option if all else fails.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using the marvelous Hi Image components for year:

http://www.hicomponents.com/main/

Very powerfull and very comprehensive.

Best of all: it's free now.

Comment: No way to download it, though.

Comment: This is a newly designed web site. I think he has forgotten to include the links.

Comment: Anyone have a link to the free version of this? Their website only seems to contain paid-for versions now...