# Delphi 2005 TPngImage or Equivalent?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2005

I see from this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584522/is-there-a-delphi-5-component-that-can-handle-png-files), and the Nick Hodges [blog](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/nickhodges/2008/08/13/39100), that the TPngImage has been rolled into Delphi. That's great and all, but we've got a project that's stuck in D2005 and we need to do a simple conversion from PNG to BMP.  Is there anywhere that we can get the legitimate source for this? I do not want to run afoul of Embarcadero's licensing, but I DO want to pave the way for a smooth transition to DelphiXE2 (or 3, or 9, who knows when we'll actually convert?). Suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: There was a lot of mis-information on that blog of Nick's. Nick was attempting to say that it was not possible for the original code to be distributed following Embarcadero's purchase of it. There was nothing in the original license to back up this viewpoint. Download the code using the link that RRUZ provides and you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks David, I was hoping that was the case.

Comment: As of today, it can still be downloaded from [here on bitbucket](https://github.com/JackTrapper/pngdelphi) (contains a small bug-fix with explanation, by Ian Boyd).

It's also on [soureforge here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pngdelphi2), which has some adjustments to make it compatible with to Delphi 2010 (i.e. every string changed to AnsiString), but there are no obj files, which I think are needed. 

Both of these give attribution to Gustavo Daud, but whether modified versions of his code can be legally used, I do not know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The original version of the `TPNGImage` from Gustavo Daud is available in the torry's site http://www.torry.net/authorsmore.php?id=6929

Comment: a small note: the class names are different `TPngObject` (old) -> `TPngImage` (new)

Answer (score 0):

You may also consider using the GR32 PNG library. https://sourceforge.net/projects/gr32pnglibrary/

It is a PNG library for reading and writing of PNG images in combination with a TBitmap32 class from the GR32 library.